# Flying-saucer ignores word-wrap

Tags: java, flying-saucer

Has anyone here gotten `word-wrap: break-word` to work in `flying-saucer`? I'm rendering `html to png` in `flying-saucer`. I can find a 3 years old topic [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/flying-saucer-users/word-wrap%7Csort%3arelevance%7Cspell%3atrue/flying-saucer-users/0Z7GHcVhKhY/IkIPrxapPkYJ) with a supposed fix, but I can't recompile flying-saucer by myself, since they didn't include their dependencies into their download. Then I tried to build it using their `build.xml` in eclipse, but it's lacking a javac task.

I tried using a `table` with `table-layout:fixed`, flying-saucer ignores that as well. Has anyone succeeded with this before?

Attached you will find a sketch of my problem.

```
  my div in a browser
 ________________
|                |
|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|
|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|
|WWWWWWWWW       |
|________________|


  my div in flying-saucer
 ________________
|                |
|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
|________________|
```

Comment: Just tried using zero width spaces `&#8203` and `<wbr>` and `white-space: pre-wrap?`. This is also ignored. If anyone has ever got any kind of word-breaking to work in flying-saucer, I'd love to read about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with flying-saucer myself but right there in the tag description it says it is a renderer for CSS 2.1 content and [word-wrap is CSS 3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon this question and found that using `word-wrap: break-word` actually is possible using Flying Saucer.

It is true that [word-wrap is CSS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22226541/3508303) but the discussion you linked mentions a [commit](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/commit/9b0c5cbffa46e38b2f3d66e3c97d86518598ac45) that adds support for `word-wrap` to Flying Saucer. This change is included in the versions of Flying Saucer [distributed through Maven](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer#getting-flying-saucer). Make sure you're using at least version 9.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue and used 
 word-break : break-all;
This was fixed.